# Unordered Selections

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> A survey is conducted and $3$ people are to be chosen from a group of $20$.
>
> a) In how many different ways could the $3$ be chosen? ($1140$)
>
> b) If a group contains $8$ men and $12$ women, how many groups containing exactly $1$ man are possible? ($528$)

A solution for question b) is wanted. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to select three people, you need to select one man and two women. The number of possible groups thus equals:

$${8 \choose 1}{12 \choose 2} = 8 \cdot 66 = 528$$